# Can I make a map for my game as a Component in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

This is my code.

```
            package gui;

            import java.awt.Component;
            import world.Terrain;
            import world.World;

            public class Map extends Component
            {
                private World world;
                private Terrain[][] terrainMap;
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                /*
                 * I want to make a map that can be added to the JFrame of this game that will visually show the world map of this game
                 */

                private void generateMap()
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x < world.regions.length; x++)
                    {
                        for(int y = 0; y < world.regions[x].length; y++)
                        {
                            terrainMap[x][y] = world.regions[x][y].getTerrain();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This method should take the relevant information from the world I want to map for the purposes of this general world map, and this class extends Component, so I should be able to add it to the JFrame. The question is, how do I make it so that it renders a visual map as an actual component when I boot this game?

To be more specific. I am making a mostly text based game but I want a somewhat low quality world map of the game. I wanted to make it as a Component, like JLabels, or Buttons, but a custom world map. How do I design it so it will actually appear on screen?

Comment: Please clarify more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the original post. Does this help you know more what I'm wanting to do?

Comment: Its not coding problem, its design problem, right?

Comment: I got the whole class to finally show. I'm new to GUI's and I would really like the map to show. If I have the whole approach wrong I could use that advice too.

Comment: provide code for world.Terrain ,world.World class also.

Comment: Draw it to a BufferedImage and simply display it as image

Comment: MadProgrammer how exactly does that work? It sounds easier than what I am trying to do now

Comment: First use swing, not awt (obsolete since many years). You need to provide custom implementation for few methods, `paintComponent` for on-screen rendering, `getPreferredSize` for layout at least. Read about "custom component in swing", there exists a lot of examples.